# Added text before an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add some text just before the anchor tag I click on.  The following adds the text to the actual anchor tag itself:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".none_standard_links").live('click', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).prepend("test");
    });
});
```

the above gives me html as shown below:

Before the link is clicked

```
<a href="#" class="none_standard_links">link one</a>
```

After the link is clicked

```
<a href="#" class="none_standard_links">testlink one</a>
```

What I want is this:

```
test<a href="#" class="none_standard_links">link one</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".none_standard_links").live('click', function(event)
    {
        $(this).before("test");
    });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ukuje4)

Comment: I'm not sure why I dropped the `event.preventDefault();` from that. FWIW, there's no reason, it's not part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of prepend() use [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

So it would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".none_standard_links").live('click', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).before("test");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the before() function. Should be what you need

```
$(this).before("test");
```

http://api.jquery.com/before/

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/):

```
$(this).before('something');
```

You can use [`.insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/), but it is slightly more verbose since you have to explicitly create a text node:

```
$(document.createTextNode("hello")).insertBefore("a");
```

[**Try them here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pSKnX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) instead

```
 $(this).before("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/):

`$(this).before("test");`